# ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed

Tags: android, ubuntu, ioctl, chroot

ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed

I already ask about similar problem but I wrote some more detail here

to run the ubuntu in android,
I made an img file with rootstock
rootstock -f kty1104-ThinkPad-Z60t -l kty1104 -p 1 --imagesize 2047M --notarball --seed linux-image-omap,lxde,build-essential,openssh-server,tightvncserver,x11-xserver-utils

this img can chrooted on my ubuntu PC by
sudo mount -o loop,noatime -t ext2 /home/kty1104/ubuntu.img /mnt
sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt /bin/bash

but when I try to this mount ~ chroot command on my android,
it says, ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Bad file number on mount command
and when I just to force to chroot, it says "segment fault"

I think the problems comes from rootstock command
could somebody help me?

Comment: If this is just additional information regarding a question you already asked, please edit that question instead of starting a new one.  Or at least link to the original question in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this myself today and then did some research.  It seems that the kernels of stock ROMs don't support loop devices.  If you're desperate and experienced, you may try building a custom kernel.  If there's another way to accomplish your goal without loop devices, you should go with that instead, since messing with kernels on embedded systems can have unexpected and/or irreversible effects(brick) if done wrong.  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5218/can-i-mount-loopdevice-in-android